# presentation setup: mirror individual window in GNOME's extended screen mode

Tags: gnome, multi-monitor, gnome-shell

In lectures and presentations, I sometimes switch between showing slides and live coding.

When showing slides, I like to have the speaker's view on my own screen (the built-in one of my laptop) and the fullscreen current slide on the projector (a.k.a. "beamer") for the audience. (I do this with `pdfpc`, but LibreOffice Impress and even reveal.js each have a similar mode.)

When live coding, I obviously want me (on my laptop screen) *and* the audience (via the projector) to *both* see my IDE. (VSCodium, but could also be any other.)

Currently, when switching between showing slides an live coding, I thus switch GNOME 45.4 between "extended" (different windows on different monitors) and "mirrored" mode (same content on all monitors). Even though there are keyboard shortcuts (<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> on my laptop) for this, this is much more cumbersome than just switching between windows / applications (which I additionally have to do anyway).

Thus, **can I stay in extended mode, but have *one* window or application (my IDE) shown "mirrored" on both / all monitors?** I suspect there might be GNOME shell extensions providing such functionality, but I wasn't yet able to find one with the search terms I tried.